# Quoting in VBscript

Tags: vbscript, quoting

I am using vbscript to query an "at" job that is executing a specific command and I believe I have the quoting wrong. I have confirmed the script works as intended when I query something that does not contain spaces or quotes; however when I query for something that contains spaces and quotes I do not get the desired results. The exact value I want to find is:
cmd /c "C:\Test Folder\Folder1\Blah.cmd"

Here is the code I am using:

```
strComputer = "."
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"_
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRandJob = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
            ("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob WHERE Command='cmd /c ""C:\Test Folder\Folder1\Blah.cmd""' ")

For Each objJob in colRandJob
            WScript.Echo "Found  AT Job with ID " + CStr(objJob.JobID)
Next
```

I have tried a few different things and cant seem to find the right way. Can someone help me out and let me know the proper way to do this?

**Update**

I was able to resolve the issue by doing the following (I am only including the relevant lines) I have not tested this without the double back slash's in the path, but I believe it is required along with the new quoting I have used:

```
'Assign the string I'm looking for to a variable
set targetCmd = "cmd /c "C:\\Test Folder\\Folder1\\Blah.cmd""

Set colRandJob = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob WHERE Command='" & targetCmd & "' ")
```

Comment: Do you get anything if you remove the `WHERE` clause (ie select all jobs)? I tried it and had no output

Comment: The syntax you've been used is purely correct. It seems, there is no equality for your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `""""` to produce a string containing only `"` and also use `&` to concatenate your string first.

```
mystring = "cmd /c " & """"C:\Test Folder\Folder1\Blah.cmd"""
```

(not tested )

Comment: shouldn't it be `"""C:\Test Folder\Folder1\Blah.cmd"""`? ie you have too many double quotes

Comment: I was just addressing the not-compiling issue. agreed, the OP has the quotes correct in the question

Answer (score 0):

Backslash (`\`) is an escape character in WMI. So, WMI queries must use double backslashes `\\` in place of each single backslash:

```
Set colRandJob = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob WHERE Command='cmd /c ""C:\\Test Folder\\Folder1\\Blah.cmd""' ")
```

Comment: I believe that was part of the issue. I have updated my post with what eventually worked for me.